# dúvida sobre functions em javascript

Tags: javascript

quando devo usar function `nomeDaFunction(){}` e `var algumaFunction = function(){}` ? existe uma maneira correta ou a maneira de boa prática?
em meus programas, sempre usei `nomeDaFunction(){}` , mas vi muitas pessoas usando a outra forma.